# Django, TemplateDoesNotExist error: Heroku can't find template directory. How to show it where to look?

Tags: django, templates, heroku, django-templates

I've done much clicking and syncdb'ing and have yet to find a solution. I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /quotes/
quotes/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://quoteboard94.herokuapp.com/quotes/
Django Version: 1.4.4 
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
quotes/index.html
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

My settings have this:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) #for heroku

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '/templates/'), # for heroku
    '/Users/jacksongonzales/projects/QuoteBoard/templates/',
)
```

`import os.path` is up top as well.

That path under TEMPLATE_DIRS is the absolute path to my templates.

Am I not punching in the right stuff for PROJECT_DIR and TEMPLATE_DIRS variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my set up for a heroku project.

```
# here() gives us file paths from the root of the system to the directory
# holding the current file.
here = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
# root() gives us file paths from the root of the system to whatever
# folder(s) we pass it starting at the parent directory of the current file.
root = lambda * x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)

....

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    root('templates'),
)
```

UPDATE:
My project has the same local template structure as the one it's deployed with, so I don't need to add a direct path in my templates directory. You have one in yours:

```
'/Users/jacksongonzales/projects/QuoteBoard/templates/',
```

If your first entry in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is correct, do you need the second one?

Comment: Great thanks! Success! Part of my error might have been in not putting PROJECT_ROOT at the top of my settings file. Edit: Also, I didn't need the second file path in TEMPLATE_DIRS. It was just there as a dummy for local use.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should be

`os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'), # for heroku`

without the slashes.

`os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '/templates/'), # for heroku`

returns `/templates/` not the path you would expect

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on
>   Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are
>   thrown away, and joining continues.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the tip and reference to the docs. I didn't fully understand the function before.